# c# - TFS 2015 Service hook to post HTTP call to Slack

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

Have been working on creating a custom TFS Service Hook which 'll post (HTTP) notification to Slack.

My requirement is to POST a HTTP call to slack when a Bug workitem's status is changed to Inprogress . (I have Implemented the same with TFS Server side plugin .unfortunately , I had to go for Service Hook over Plugin)

I tried the below code with TFS 2017 onprem with PAT, unfortunately it was breaking. am I doing anything wrong ? I want my code to work in 2015.2 without PAT.

Can someone help please ?

```
public async static void CreateServiceHook(string collName, string projName, string projId, string AccessToken)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);

           string url = "https://" + collName + ".visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/" + projName + "?includecapabilities=true&api-version=1.0";
            HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), url);
            var response = client.SendAsync(req).Result;
            string contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        //create service hook
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
            var request = new
            {
                publisherId = "tfs",
                eventType = "workitem.created",
                consumerId = "webHooks",
                consumerActionId = "httpRequest",
                scope = "project",
                publisherInputs = new {
                  //  buildStatus = "",
                    projectId = projId 
                },
                consumerInputs = new
                {
                    url = "https://slack.api.com/services/XXXXXXXXXX
                }

            };
            var response = client.PostAsync("https://" + collName + ".visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions/?api-version=1.0",
                new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request).ToString(),
                    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                    .Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
                    response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                    .Result);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies. 
What I want to achieve is moment work item status gets changed in TFS , I have to post http call to Slack. 
I have 4 http calls which ll create a channel , archive, del etc. Since my code is not posting HTTP call to slack , I have posted here to check if my code has some problem.

Comment: @user2153844 What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

TFS has default slack service hook which can post a message to a channel. So instead of using `web hooks` consumer, you can use `slack` consumer. And you can only achieve is posting messages to Slack when a Bug workitem's status is updated.

The API looks like below:

```
POST http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=3.2
Content-Type: application/json
{
"consumerActionId":"postMessageToChannel",
"consumerId":"slack",
"consumerInputs":{
    "url":"https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx"},
    "eventType":"workitem.updated",
    "publisherId":"tfs",
    "publisherInputs":{
        "areaPath":"",
        "workItemType":"Bug",
        "changedFields":"System.State",
        "projectId":"77e3c775-dc30-4354-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"},
        "scope":1
}
```